# Websphere EAR limit

Tags: websphere, ear

WebSphere Application Server 8.0.0.0

I am using RAD to make Host Access Transformation Services (HATS) macros and deploy them as webservices on WAS. I'm a .NET developer and have no (very little) experience with WAS and Java EE.
When I was discussing some things with people who have more experience it was mentioned that we should avoid making multiple EAR files and deploying them onto WAS. It would be preferred if we could keep them as low as possible, ideal would be only a single EAR deployed. The WAR modules are fine if masses of them exist.

Is there any truth in this or would it be ok if we have more EAR files deployed on WAS?

Comment: Did they give any reason for why multiple EARs is a "bad" thing?

Comment: I believe it was more of a performance issue, but I do not recall exactly. I will ask the guy (who was setting up RAD and WAS) what could the issues be. I just wanted some opinions from people who actually run lots of applications on WAS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen any warning like that, and we run 20-30 EARs on our servers. It's definitely supported and expected that you run multiple Enterprise Applications (EARs).

Comment: I thought so. I will try to keep the numbers low but if the need be I will make new EARs.